# Conditional section title [ifthenelse] not working

Tags: sectioning, conditionals, etoolbox, optional-arguments

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm,amssymb}

\newcommand{\probName}{}%
\newcounter{probCounter}%
\setcounter{probCounter}{1}
\newcounter{partCounter}%

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\howmany}[2][subsection]{%
  \begingroup
  \@namedef{the#1}{\arabic{#1}}%
  \addtocounter{#1}{\m@ne}%
  \refstepcounter{#1}%
  \label{#2}%
  \endgroup}
\makeatother

\newenvironment{prob}[1][]%
  {\setcounter{partCounter}{0}
   \renewcommand{\probName}{#1}%
   \newcommand{\abc}{\ref{noPart:\arabic{probCounter}}}
   \section{{Problem \arabic{probCounter}}{: \probName} (contains
   \abc\
   %\ifthenelse{\abc=0}{1}{\abc}\  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% does not work 
    parts) }% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% wanna conditional parts/part

  }{\howmany{noPart:\arabic{probCounter}}
   \stepcounter{probCounter}%
  }

\newcommand{\partName}{}%
\renewenvironment{part}[1][]%
  {\stepcounter{partCounter}%
   \renewcommand{\partName}{#1}%
   \subsection{{Part \Alph{partCounter}}{: \partName}}
  }{}

\newenvironment{ques}[1][]{
    \ifthenelse{
        \equal{#1}{}
    }{}{
        \ifthenelse{
            \equal{#1}{1}
        }{
            \textbf{(#1 point)}
        }{
            \textbf{(#1 points)}
        }}
    }{}

\begin{document}

\begin{prob}[Prob 1]
\begin{part}
\end{part}

\begin{part}
\end{part}

\begin{part}
\end{part}
\end{prob}


\begin{prob}[Prob 2] %%%%%%%%%%% force to show => (contains 1 part)
\end{prob}

\begin{prob}[Prob 3] %%%%%%%%%%% correct the grammar => (contains 1 part)
\begin{part}
\end{part}
\end{prob}

\begin{prob}[Prob 4]
\begin{part}
\end{part}
\begin{part}
\end{part}
\begin{part}
\end{part}
\begin{part}
\end{part}
\end{prob}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Now I wanna it to be:

...

Prob 2 **(contains 1 part)** %% force it to be 1 part

Prob 3 **(contains 1 part)** %% get rid of the "s" from the wording (part"s")

...

The first thing come to my mind is conditional ifthenelse function, which also included in my code, but it doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `\ref{...}` is not a number, but a set of instruction for *printing* a number.

You can use the `refcount` package that provides `\getrefnumber` that expands to 0 if the reference has not yet been established or to the reference itself.

I've made some other small changes (in particular protected several end-of-lines). For part/parts the syntax with `\ifthenelse` is cumbersome and I preferred using directly `\ifnum`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ifthen,refcount}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm,amssymb}

\newcommand{\probName}{}%
\newcounter{probCounter}%
\setcounter{probCounter}{1}
\newcounter{partCounter}%

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\howmany}[2][subsection]{%
  \begingroup
  \@namedef{the#1}{\arabic{#1}}%
  \addtocounter{#1}{\m@ne}%
  \refstepcounter{#1}%
  \label{#2}%
  \endgroup}
\makeatother

\newenvironment{prob}[1][]%
  {\setcounter{partCounter}{0}
   \renewcommand{\probName}{#1}%
   \edef\numberofparts{\getrefnumber{noPart:\arabic{probCounter}}}%
   \newcommand{\abc}{\ref{noPart:\arabic{probCounter}}}%
   \section{Problem \arabic{probCounter}: \probName} (contains
   \ifnum\numberofparts=0
    1 part%
   \else
     \ifnum\numberofparts=1
       1 part%
     \else
       \numberofparts\ parts%
     \fi
   \fi)%
  }{\howmany{noPart:\arabic{probCounter}}%
   \stepcounter{probCounter}%
  }

\newcommand{\partName}{}%
\renewenvironment{part}[1][]%
  {\stepcounter{partCounter}%
   \renewcommand{\partName}{#1}%
   \subsection{{Part \Alph{partCounter}}{: \partName}}%
  }{}

\newenvironment{ques}[1][]{%
    \ifthenelse{%
        \equal{#1}{}
    }{}{%
        \ifthenelse{%
            \equal{#1}{1}%
        }{%
            \textbf{(#1 point)}%
        }{%
            \textbf{(#1 points)}%
        }}%
    }{}

\begin{document}

\begin{prob}[Prob 1]
\begin{part}
\end{part}

\begin{part}
\end{part}

\begin{part}
\end{part}
\end{prob}


\begin{prob}[Prob 2] %%%%%%%%%%% force to show => (contains 1 part)
\end{prob}

\begin{prob}[Prob 3] %%%%%%%%%%% correct the grammar => (contains 1 part)
\begin{part}
\end{part}
\end{prob}

\begin{prob}[Prob 4]
\begin{part}
\end{part}
\begin{part}
\end{part}
\begin{part}
\end{part}
\begin{part}
\end{part}
\end{prob}

\end{document}
```

[image]